Application not meeting expected ethernet Speed
I am using a Getac Semi Rugged Laptop installed with Ubuntu 22.04. when I run Iperf application its reaching 900Mbps but when I run my simple TCP client server application its not reaching 80Mbps stopping at 40Mbps only .
The Application details : 2 instances of a TCP client applications running with different ports and connecting to 2 different hardware TCP servers , each sending 1024 packets of request and getting 4338 packet of reply from Hardware. When I run this applications in laptop am not racing expected speed .
But when I run a other basic client server application with 4338 packet sending and receiving ,  its meeting the speed up to 800Mbps.
I have checked all jumbo frames , buffer sizes etc .
The same application is running in other laptops which is having same OS version.
The laptop which am facing issue is having intel based Ethernet card . The same laptop is having USB based Ethernet card also , in this USB ethernet my application is working .
SO , is the issue with Card or OS . which configuration settings of the ethenrt I need to check .
Here I am attaching the OS and Laptop details , Lenovo Laptop its working. S410 Getac Lapotp PCI card not working but USB ethernet its working.
enter image description here
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

The screenshot is from a Windows device. How does it relate to your question? What have you done to verify performance? What does system logs show?

Yes, to give the exact details of Ethernet card present in the Laptop I gave this screenshot. I have used iperf to check the performance of ethernet , am getting up to 900Mbps with that but my custom application is not meeting the speed .

Are you running the application on Windows or on Ubuntu?

Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS
